# Django-photologue ImageModel

Tags: django, photologue

This is my first project in django and im using photologue for gallery, which is awesome and i really like it.

But there is one thing i dont get, how can i use its ImageModel?

I have a blog-app and with every new blogpost created in the admin interface i woud like to upload a image which is linked to that post.

```
from django.db import models
from tagging.fields import TagField
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models
from photologue.models import ImageModel
#import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TagField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thumbnail = ImageModel()


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

This code above doesn't seem to work or do anything in fact.

I have been rifling through the docs, google ect and trying to understand the photologue source myself but i cant seem to get it to work like i want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageModel` is an *abstract* class. You can't use it as itself. Instead, you must subclass it:

```
class BlogImage(ImageModel):
    pass

class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(BlogImage, related_name='blogs')
```

But, the main purpose of `ImageModel` is to allow you to create a photo model with additional custom data that still behaves like one of photologue's models. photologue already has `Photo` which is a real model based on `ImageModel` that you can use if you just need the defaults.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='blogs')
```

Comment: so i can't use photologue to link one image to each blogpost?

Comment: Huh? I just showed you how you can. Use `Photo` if you don't need additional data unique to your application on the photo. Otherwise, subclass `ImageModel`, add your extra fields/methods, and then use that subclass.